# How to use Render Props in functional component using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert my React app (create-react-app) to use Typescript and I've hit a hurdle with a component that uses render props.

Here's a simplified version which still has the error...

```
import React from 'react'

type Props = {
    fullWidth?: boolean,
    renderRightSection?: React.ReactNode
}

const Component = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>((props, ref) => {

    let {fullWidth, renderRightSection, ...inputProps} = props

    return (

        <InputWrapper fullWidth={props.fullWidth}>

            <input {...inputProps} ref={ref} />

            {renderRightSection && renderRightSection()}

        </InputWrapper>

    )

})
```

The error is with the **renderRightSection()** bit and looks like this:

```
let renderRightSection: string | number | true | {} | React.ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => React.ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => React.Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => React.Component<...>)> | React.ReactNodeArray | React.ReactPortal
This expression is not callable.
  No constituent of type 'string | number | true | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal' is callable.ts(2349)
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

**Edit:**

To show how I am using the component in a form:

```
<Textbox 
    name="username" 
    type="text" 
    fullWidth={true} 
    placeholder="Choose a Username" 
    renderRightSection={() => (
        <TextboxBadge>
            {usernameAvailable && <span>Available</span>}
            {!usernameAvailable && <span>Taken</span>}
        </TextboxBadge>
    )}
/>
```

**Edit:**

And here's what it's used for, rendering a block of JSX on the right hand side of the textbox.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved the problem. It seems that when creating the type for the component the render prop needs to be a function which returns JSX. I had no idea that you could do this:

```
type Props = {
    fullWidth?: boolean,
    className?: string,
    renderRightSection?: () => JSX.Element
}
```

But it worked!

Answer (score -1):

I used the accepted answer, and it worked, but I didn't like it. I was able to get this working by typing the component being passed in as `ReactNode` and then calling it like this:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
    detailComponent: ReactNode;
}

const MyComponent = ({ detailComponent }: MyComponentProps) => {
    return <div>{detailComponent}</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

This is what it looks like when called from the parent:

```
const myComponent = <OfficeDetail />;
    
return <MyComponent detailComponent={myComponent} />;
```

Comment: This isn't a render prop, that's just a react child.

Comment: @LeonardoPetrucci How is it a react child? I'm passing it in as a prop, not as a child. For the example, I chose to render it inside of a div, but there could be other props, including children, and this render prop could still be passed in. I'm a little surprised at the downvotes since this is a pretty elegant approach.

Comment: Yeah you're passing children as a prop, that's not a render prop.

Comment: @lpetrucci I don't get it, what's a render prop then? AFAIC when you don't use the "children" prop (which is the one for the semantic notation within parent component's tag), you are using a render prop then. Why is this just a react child if the prop's name is "detailComponent"?

Comment: @Umagon old docs about render props https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html